# Need help about htaccess to redirect folder back to root

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, directory

i'll to the point. i've structure folder like below :

```
root
|- app
|-- index.php
|- other_folder
```

and my .htaccess is like this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -Indexes
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    Rewritecond %{HTTP_HOST} ^root
    RewriteRule ^$ app/index.php [L]
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/app%{REQUEST_URI} -f
    RewriteRule .* app/$0 [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule .* app/$0 [QSA]
    RewriteRule ^app$ . [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

ok, i totally don't understand about it. just plug and play, trial and error. i make thos htaccess to :

1. when **root** accessed it run **app/index.php**
2. when **root/index.php** accessed it run **app/index.php**
3. when **root/other_folder** accessed still accessed the **other_folder**
4. when **root/app** accessed it will redirect back to **root**
5. when **root/app/index.php/any** accessed it will redirect to **root/index.php/any**
6. when **root/index.php/any** accessed it will run **root/app/index.php/any**

Now, the problem is folder **app** still accessed and not redirect back to **root**. SO anyone could help me with this problem :( thanks before and forgive me about my bad english.